# Attempt to insert record in MySQL db via PDO causes two records to be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to insert records into MySQL database but it's inserting a duplicate record and I cannot figure out why it's doing this and was wondering if someone could help me with this.  I read the data in from a binary file.  The database table has five columns: ID, date stamp,functionName, realWebGLData,imagWebGLData

The webGLData are large blobs and in the example below, I only read the real data file and only insert the realWebGLData blob but it duplicates the record when I load all the columns as well.  And when I inspect the database I have two records (different auto increment IDs) for the same data with a timestamp almost idential.

The functionName is extracted from the first 512 bytes of the file record.  Here is my function to insert a blob into the database:

```
public function insertBlob($filePath) {

        $blob = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
        if(!$blob)
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        $theFunctionName=fread($blob,512);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO functiondatabase(functionName,realWebGLData)
                VALUES(:functionName,:realWebGLData)";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':functionName', $theFunctionName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':realWebGLData', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

And here is the PHP file that calls the insert method:

```
<?php


include 'algebraicFunctionBlobClass.php';

$blobObj = new algebraicFunctionBlob();


// store blob in database
 $blobObj->insertBlob('RealgebraicBlob.bin');

// comment out the echo for testing
//echo $a['realWebGLData'];
?>
```

Comment: There's is nothing in the code provided that would insert 2 rows, unless you were running it twice.

Comment: The date stamp, are you using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for that field?
If so, are the timestamps exactly the same?

Most likely, as @JonStirling says, you're running it twice somehow, and the timestamp should tell you that as they would be different.

Comment: Side note: You're not closing the file handle. Although it will be closed implicitly, it is a good practice to close it yourself IMO.

Comment: I am using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and sometimes both records have the same timestamp and other times they are off by a second so somehow I'm running it twice.

Comment: I added fclose($blob) and ran it again and it's still posting two records.  Will keep working on it.

Comment: Ok sorry for duplicate.  I read the reference and then tracked it down to the way I was running Chrome in Netbeans  For some reason, Netbeans is running the application twice and I had noticed that the plot appeared to be rendering twice.  This does not happen with Firefox, Edge, and IE.  Will work on this.